# Apache Tomcat Configuration Web.xml

Tags: apache, tomcat, web.xml

Hey I am having problem configuring java file in web.xml. I created a java file in examples/classes folder provided by apache tomcat by default. and added this lines to web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Time_Display</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Time_Display</servlet-class>
```

and it runs fine at location url:port/examples/servlet/Time_Display

Now I duplicated the whole examples folder to examples1 and running the above modified link

url:port/examples1/servlet/Time_Display

then its saying "The requested resource (/examples1/servlet/Time_Display) is not available."

Why ??

here is my full web.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

<display-name>Tomcat Examples</display-name>
<description>
  Tomcat Example servlets and JSP pages.
</description>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Time_Display</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Time_Display</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Time_Display</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Time_Display</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be some problem with tomcat configuration (exploded war auto deploy may be disabled). Restart tomcat and try accessing above link.

Comment: Can you paste the `web.xml` in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use servlet in the URL in calling your servlet  (url:port/examples1/servlet/Time_Display) since you provided servlet-mapping in your web.xml.

Probably   examples1/Time_Display will work.

Using servlet in your URL is needed when you utilize org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet in your application.  It is not recommended in modern Tomcat servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you got a 404 error informing that "The requested resource is not available" that means this url is not correctly mapped.

In your web.xml, change your element 'url-pattern' to /examples1/servlet/Time_Display
This must resolve your problem.

As you have put the element 'servlet-class' as Time_Display, I guess the class Time_Display is in the default package. If not, you must inform the complete name of the class, that is, packageName+className, for example com.example.Time_Display.